# access @Remote EJB deployed in WAR on JBoss 7.1.1 from standalone client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, war

I'm a bit lost. I've been googling around for quite long time.
Is it possible to access EJB with `@Remote` that is packaged into WAR file from standalone java client? I'm using JBoss 7.1.1 and every combination of JNDI names I try I keep getting NameNotFoundException.

I can't find anything about that in doc. It is only said that in the Java EE web profile `@Remote` is not supported, but I suppose that if I'm running it on JBoss 7.1.1 it is run on the full profile not on the web one (just because it is packaged in WAR).

Answer (score 2):

Try [this doc](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI).
If this is too long for you, you can check out my example code at [github](https://github.com/mmazi/jboss-ee/tree/master/client)

Important things to note:

1. See your `jboss/bin/client/README.txt` for how to easily include the
   relevant libraries
2. Use the `ejb:/...` name for lookup; the
   `java:...` names you see in log at deploy are note remotely exposed
3. The two `*.properties` files: in some cases (when some libraries are
   missing etc.) you might think you need to add something into them,
   but they're fine; make sure you set up everything else correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate an EAR file.. that means you have a Java EE application not only web. Then you'll be able to locate and call your remote EJB from a java client.